# Why orderby filter is not working?

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-orderby

I am applying a 'orderby' filter but its not working. I am getting data from an API which I double check, is coming for sure. But the filter is not working.

```
 <div class="filter-container">
      <select class="form-control" ng-model="userOrder">
         <option value="0">No</option>
         <option value="1">Yes</option>
      </select>
 </div>

 <tr class="odd" ng-repeat="user in allusers | filter: query1 | filter: query2 | filter: query3 | filter: query4 | filter: query5 | orderBy: userOrder">       
     <td>
         <span ng-if="user.superuser==1">Yes</span>
         <span ng-if="user.superuser==0">No</span>
     </td>      
     <td>
         <span ng-if="user.status==0">Not active</span>
         <span ng-if="user.status==1">Active</span>
         <span ng-if="user.status==-1">Banned</span>
     </td>            
 </tr>
```

My controller:

```
$scope.user = function () {
    $http.get('http://event/users/users/')
        .success(function (data) {
            $scope.allusers = data;
            console.log("all users data coming in user function");                   
        })
        .error(function (data) {
            console.log('error');
        });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In order by you need to pass the element of the array like if you have `allusers` as bellow. then `userOrder` should be  `name` OR `lastname`

> https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy help you more.

change your drop down with bellow and try.

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="userOrder">
     <option value="username">Username</option>
     <option value="email">Email</option>     
</select>
```

Comment: I write the same code in  another project and it was working out there but not here,

Comment: @UsmanIqbal can you please write the dummy data what is in $scope.allusers?

Comment: [{"id":"1","access_token":"21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3","username":"admin","email":"webmaster@example.com","create_at":"2015-12-17 00:00:00","lastvisit_at":"2016-08-25 07:28:17","superuser":"1","status":"1","password":null,"activkey":null,"salt":null,"requires_new_password":null,"login_attempts":null,"login_time":null,"login_ip":null,"activation_key":null,"validation_key":null,"create_time":null,"update_time":null,"reset_token":null,"profilepic":null}]

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to order by `superuser` property of `user` object.

You should do this:

```
orderBy : "superuser"
```

If you want your select box to controller whether to order in descending order or ascending, do this:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="sortReversed">
       <option value="False">No</option>
       <option value="True">Yes</option>
</select>

...

orderBy : "superuser" : sortReversed
```

Hope it helps

Comment: applied your answer, when i choose No, i still see 'No' in results, and if i choose yes no change.